# Passing element to jQuery function

Tags: jquery, html

I need to change the text of a html span element in a timer.
The timer works well, but I have no sucess changing the span content.

The problem is at:

```
$(element).text(hour);
```

What am I missing here?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<span id="mytimer">00:00</span>
```

Here is my JS:

```
function loaded(selector, callback){
        $(function () {
            callback($(selector));
        });
        $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', selector, function () {
            callback($(this));
        });
   };

   function setupTimer(element, duration, interval) {
        var start = Date.now(),
            diff,
            minutes,
            seconds;
        clearInterval(window.mytimer);
        function timer() {
            diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
            minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
            seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;
            if (minutes < 0) {
              minutes = 0;
            }
            if (seconds < 0) {
              seconds = 0;
            }
            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
            hour=minutes + ":" + seconds;
            $(element).text(hour);
            if (window.mytimer != null & diff < 0) {
              clearInterval(window.mytimer);
            }
        };
        timer();
        window.mytimer = setInterval(timer, interval * 1000);
    };

   loaded('#mytimer', function(el){
          setupTimer(el,100,1);
   });
```

Comment: is element is already a selected jQuery object, you could just use `element.text(hour);` no need to select it twice

Comment: @Daniel Corzo Why would that help? `hour` contains text and `.text(argument)` is a valid Jquery method to replace the children of an element with a text node containing the passed argument.

Comment: @DanielCorzo, why would `.html()` would work but .`text() ` wouldn't?

Comment: Where do you call `loaded`?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn´t work. I have a valid "mytimer" element found on loaded function. But into setuptimer fiunction the line $(element).text(hour) or html(hour) doesn´t  work.

Comment: try with `element` instead of `$(element)`

Comment: @Kaddath i alread dit it. It doesn't work

Comment: try it like this setupTimer($('mytimer'), 100, 1); and leave out the loaded method.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `hour=minutes + ":" + seconds;`
I suspect it isn't changing.

Comment: @bobjoe  loaded() is a special function theat trigger after the page loaded. I just use  in a script  before body close tag. I can see that loaded is working, the problem is after I pass the element found(mytimer) to setuptimer. There the element doesn´t works.

Comment: @bobjoe  on debug hour is ok with your values.

Comment: @LuizAlves the loaded method is the problem - have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/vnra3zn9/

Comment: @axel.michel I see, but I have the next workink well in other case:    loaded('#divpager', function(el){
      el.css('display', 'none');
   });    
Why this is work?

Comment: if you have two starting points possible, do a loader function that stores the started value of the two events, depending on your case, fire the start from this function when one of the two responded, or both if you need the 2 to be ready for your page start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this is an additional answer to the one of Kaddath, he is correct, as I mentioned in the comments above, *remove your loaded method* (or at least a part of it).

**Why?**

- [DOMNodeInserted](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2802011) is deprecated and has a negative impact on
  performance.
- Whenever you change the content (HTML/Text) of this element you trigger a new inserted event, that is the reason why your timer does not work.

If you really need to "wait", as you described in your comment beow, you could use `mutationobserver` which "replaces" the `DOMNodeInserted` logic. I put together a small [example](https://jsfiddle.net/szt81rg7/1/)

```
$().ready(function() {

  function setupTimer(element, duration, interval) {
    var start = Date.now(),
        diff,
        minutes,
        seconds;
    clearInterval(window.mytimer);
    function timer() {
        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;
        if (minutes < 0) {
          minutes = 0;
        }
        if (seconds < 0) {
          seconds = 0;
        }
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        hour=minutes + ":" + seconds;
        element.text(hour);
        if (window.mytimer != null & diff < 0) {
          clearInterval(window.mytimer);
        }
    };
    timer();
    window.mytimer = setInterval(timer, interval * 1000);
  };

  // simply run your method here (in case DOM element exists)
  // setupTimer($('#mytimer'),100,1);  

  // in case your element is not there you can 
  // observe the document for changes like this...
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function( mutations ) {
      mutations.forEach(function( mutation ) {
        var newNodes = mutation.addedNodes; // DOM NodeList
        if( newNodes !== null ) { // If there are new nodes added
            var $nodes = $( newNodes ); // jQuery set
            $nodes.each(function() {
                var $node = $( this );
                // looking for your element
                if( $node.attr('id') === 'mytimer') {
                    // do your action
                    setupTimer($('#mytimer'),100,1);
                    // in case you do not need it any longer
                    observer.disconnect();
                }
            });
        }
      });    
    });

    // Configuration of the observer:
    // might be possible to reduce this in your case
    var config = { 
        attributes: true, 
        childList: true, 
        characterData: true 
    };

    // the target has to be an existing DOM node
    // adapt this to your needs...
    var target = document.body;

    // Pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
    observer.observe(target, config);

});
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn´t work to me because mytimer  is created at runtime. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Thank Axel , I know a few about "on" and delegate. But what On method should I use to trigger the timer after the span(with the timer) be created dinamically?

Comment: @LuizAlves so why don't you call the method setupTimer when you create the element?

Comment: @LuizAlves can you provide the code part where / which creates the timer element?

Comment: Sorry, the app is more complicated. I use Intraweb with templates. So I have a template to header and footer common to all app. When I load a page(intraweb form), I have somes JS function to load and mount the complete page. The timer is on the header.html file and it is loaded when I mount the page. Sometimes happens when $().ready runs, some tags, as mytimer is not available yet. So, I use delegate and domnodeinserted when I need to solve it. I can´t use php or asp.

Comment: Thank Axel, I will follow your tips. Your answer is ok to me.

Comment: @LuizAlves I have updated my answer including an jsfiddle, to demonstrate the use of mutation observer as a replacement for your loaded method. It's a rough how-to not optimized but I hope it's helpful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the part with the DOM inserted, it causes the interval to be re-created again and again, because when you do ``text()`, you insert an element.

```
function loaded(selector, callback){
    $(function () {
        callback($(selector));
    });
    /*$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', selector, function () {
        callback($(this));
    });*/
};
```

check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rzaeg38g/

Comment: Ok, but this will not  break other parts of my app? I have many dom elements in other html pages created at runtime and I need to use the callback.

Comment: If I change the code into setuptimer to: 
         /*$(element).text(hora);*/
         $('#mytimer').text(hora); it works. So I don´t understand why your answer would be correct.

Comment: see axel michel's answer, he also provides a better structured code

Comment: @LuizAlves Kaddath is correct, try the following, add a console log into your loaded method - the part with DOMNodeInserted and see how often this event is triggered (every time you change the time).

Comment: note that your code might work on a browser where the DOMNodeInserted event has been removed, on my browser, executing the code totally halted execution and i had to force-stop the script (the reason i added a stop button)

Comment: @Kaddath Thank you, I guess I will get rid off domnodeinserted and find another solution then.